# How to override emulsify libraries in .theme file in drupal 9?

Tags: drupal, components, themes

I want to override the emulsify libraries in .theme file in my custom theme. I don't want to use the custom module to override it. I only want to override it with custom theme.

I have used all the default theme hooks in theme file but it is not working. Can someone please help me in this.